# how to remove the # in my url

Tags: php, codeigniter

https://progressive.e-inkasso.dk/login#application/views/ajax/dashboard.php 
when my webpage loads there is this # and not a / i tried to route it to be only dashboard or login in the route.php file but there was no way so far that it worked.

```
$route['default_controller'] = "Register";
$route['404_override'] = '';

$route['login/(:any)/(:any)/(:any)/(:any)/(:any)'] = "Register/login";

$route['(:any)/dashboard'] = "Register/index/$1";

//$route['(.*)/login'] = "Register/login/$1";

$route['(.*)/register'] = "Register/register/$1";
```

and i have no clue how to fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it has something to do with AngularJS and its routing integrated in your website. This is not default behaviour of CodeIgniter. I inspected your page's source code and it seems to load some Angular Javascript things.

Didnt bother to munch to find what and where exactly. But my best guess is that AngularJS is doing this. You should probably redefine your question but i doubt it is possible to remove the trailing `#`. Good luck